# Backing up VMs without separate backup server

Tags: backup, hypervisor, tapedrive

We're buying a new server and are switching to a virtual environment. We want to have one physical server as a host containing several guest servers. 
We're a small organisation and we know that ideally we should have more redundancy, but it's not an option.
Some vendors recommend VMWare, some Hyper-V. Some recommend Backup Exec (V-Ray edition), some Veeam.
Since some vendors gave contradictory information on some aspects of possible combinations of hypervisor and backup program, I'm asking here.

Can we backup directly to tape or external disk, without a separate physical backup server in between, having the backup program installed in either guest or host? (we prefer not to have a separate physical backup server)

Comment: Sure, depending on what backup software and/or technique you end up using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

This is a common deployment scenario for [Veeam](http://www.veeam.com), for example. Install the Veeam software on a guest VM and perhaps present a USB or [RDX](http://www.tandbergdata.com/us/index.cfm/products/removable-disk/) drive to that specific virtual machine.

The backup software would have visibility to your other virtual machines on the same host and would write the aggregate data to the backup drive.

*You can even install a removable backup disk inside the server. See RDX drive on right-hand side of the pictured HP server.*
[image]

Comment: Thanks. So with Veeam it should work, what about Backup Exec?